# I18n error in one file, but not another in same directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I have two lib classes in my rails project.  Both print out an error using the same syntax

```
I18n.t('.config_error')
```

One file it succeeds, the other file it fails with this error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from 
/home/hellebusch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: 
#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory>
```

I cannot find the answer to this issue.  Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "." in `I18n.t('.config_error')` means `I18n` is looking for the `config_error` key in the namespace of the resource currently being rendered. So if you were rendering the `Posts#show` view, `I18n` would looking in the `posts` namespace - aka looking for a key that nested under the `posts` key.

Does that help?

Posting the classes/views which call `I18n.t('.config_error')` would be helpful.